# XAMPP Ports Change On its Own

Tags: apache, xampp, port

My Apache Ports are set to:
**80** and **443**

Looking at the XAMPP control panel a few hours later, I noticed the Ports had changed to:
**05** and **59895**

1. Would XAMPP switch to these Ports automatically for some reason after several hours?
2. Is there a danger in using/opening these Ports?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm facing similar problem...When I refresh page on localhost, Apache Port(s) number start changing into some crazy value 49505, 49506 etc. Then I get DB connection error.

Comment: phpMyAdmin si working well, only my pages are stopped with DB connection error

Comment: Well, I found out, that my pages had been trying to connect to remote DB (I'm using two databases). I moved the remote DB to localhost and change MySQL connestion parameters...Apache is now not changing ports and everything works great.

Comment: found any solution yet or at least a proper description why this happened? ( i m facing the same problem )

Comment: I faced similar problem, accompanied by appearance of mysterious .goutputstream files - not sure whether these two strange behaviours are directly related. See my question on SU for details: http://superuser.com/q/878477/373304

Comment: @vbenitogo did you got fixed this one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Same problem was answered in [this post](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=197896&sid=df3bb64d241e7e17c754fa1982a0fc4c) by one of XAMPP developers. Assuming this is real (quote):

> In short, that is normal.
>   Apache listens for and accepts requests on ports 80 and 443 but it does not service requests on those ports. When you or others connect to your servers, they will be handled by other connections usually using high ports. The control panel just looks for all ports associated with a module. It is just picking up those client ports and the box to show all the ports is just not big enough to show them all.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide a useful solution.

Comment: @TerryLin that is because there is no solution, because there is no problem. Apache is running as intended. The issue is with the XAMPP control panel telling you the other (correct) ports.

Comment: `there is no problem` yes there absolutely is: xampp is showing wrong ports. Sure, it is a problem with xampp and not apache, but that doesn't mean it is not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is the full scenario i am explaining here that will clear you out :

We get a php page not responding, the first thing comes to our mind is : Is the apache service running on xampp ?

we immediately go to the xampp to check, and what we see is , the port is not 80 !!! Definitely every one will deduce the result that its port issue (same case happened to me) .

While its not the port issue. `infact xampp changes the ports for it self. while requests are recieved on 80 as normal.`

The real issue at that time is : that `our code is not connecting to Database`.

Hence . please keep in mind, there is no issue in that. Your apache is fine. Just go and check your db connection !! 
and cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you got skype?
Because automatically skype uses port:80 and or 443.

Try to change it.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this behaviour when using XDebug.
Everything in XAMPP was very slow, phpmyadmin or any website. Ports were changing almost on every request.
Commenting `[XDebug]` block on `php.ini` was my solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Xdebug installed there might be problem as XAMPP and Xdebug have some up-and-down scenarios.  Check whether Xdebug is listening to PHP. if yes disable or deactivate that listening till you finalize with the database.

Comment: I also have xdebug. I used to work in Ubuntu and the new company asked me for working in windows. Its a pain working with out a debugger.

Comment: yes but in Windows environment xDebug works with some uncontrollable issues like this port changing one.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have given right port number after your host if your My SQL required port, Generally we don't required Port in Host value.

I just made this mistake and found it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had this problem so I got here.

I understand that this is not a problema with xampp so I started to check my code.

I was working with this code last friday.

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

Today the code wasn't working so I have updated to this:

$conn = new mysqli($host."8000", $user, $pass, $database); //8000 is the apache port, you can change it to 80

It work's fine for me!

Hope this help you guys

Answer (score 0):

In my case 
problem with xdebug in some case 
solution 
update xdebugg file from xdebug site https://xdebug.org/download.php
if it not work please comment xdebug code in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue in my local PC.
I was trying with URL 
`127.0.0.1/project-name`
Then i tried with URL
`http://localhost/project-name` and it worked. I don't know how but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**The apache port get changed frequently automatically. Someone already told that it is normal. and many developers found the solution is not enough for working area.
I also found this issue basically when I try to fetch data from multiple tables using JOIN, and the multiple types of erroneous joining in the same sql statement. The erroneous data fetching harms the server methodology and occupies huge memory or return nothing for deadlocking, the ports get automatically changed and server goes to pause. With this server protect itself. 
So, write absolutely good and very logical SQL and fire to server. 
There would be another reasons also. I described here what I faced and found positive response.
Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

It's just like what captain_a answered 6 years ago. It is not your xampp error but your code does.
I had the same error when I typed

```
$host = 'localhost:8080'; //my config port
$db = 'attendance_db';
```

But the truth is:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'attendance_db';
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I press "Install Apache as a service" button, which could be found on the very left side of the Apache's row. It's usually a red "X" checkmark and when clicked the service is being installed. After that my ports were constantly 80 & 443

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'm not sure what the problem actually is, but stopping both Apache & MySQL, then clicking where the green tick boxes on the left are and pressing yes (install as a service) seemed to fix the problem.

Also, after I did that the port numbers returned to normal.

Good luck all!

Answer (score -1):

I've came across the same issue.

In my case I found a "strange" proxy config in httpd.conf.

As soon as I commented out the following lines, the issue disappeared:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It didn't fix the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it closing one project that i had opened in PhpStorm and was expected that i started to debug with Xdebug.

Answer (score -3):

you might be checking the current daemon/process ids through XAMPP control panel ..xampp does not changes port numbers on it's own..
restart your system or restart apache and you will find these numbers again changed to some other numbers..

i hope this resolves both of your queries..

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but no it is not PID(s), it is definitely the Port(s). They change back to normal when I restart Apache, but that does not answer my questions.