# XAMPP Server using Multiple ports instead port 80

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, webserver

XAMPP server should run on port : 80 by default, but here in our case XAMPP server running on multiple ports shown in the span short below. 
Why it happens and how to prevent this?

[image: Running XAMPP ON Multiple Ports]

Also TaskMgr shows two apache services running:

[image: Task Manager]

XAMPP httpd.conf file is here:

[image: httpd.conf file]

After running 2 or 3 hours XAMPP server, Server got slow and not responding where I think the problem would be generated by the multiple open ports?
Any idea? how to block and allow only port 80 as it is already by default?

Comment: Check for any ```Listen``` directives in the config files for apache.

Comment: Check out your XAMPPs apache configuration (located `/xampp/apache/conf/` what ports there are configured for Apache to `Listen` to.

Comment: ok @Bjoern and Jailout2000 let me check it. thanks for quick response.

Comment: I have added the httpd.conf file in snap shot where I have seen only port 80 is enable to listen to.

Comment: @AbdulRahman: same thing for me too..what should be done in order to correct this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP Ports Change On its Own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130952/xampp-ports-change-on-its-own)

Comment: @Kalanka you have to install the latest version of xampp i have no such issue anymore after installing the current version of xampp...

Answer (score 0):

it's mostly because of internal connections between apache and another service on the server.
for example it could be because connecting to 3306 (mysql)
to find out that you can use netstat button on the right of the xampp panel
or type this command in command prompt (DOS)

```
netstat -na
```

e.g: if you saw lots of :3306 it means that you did not close mysql connection!