# XAMPP Apache changing port by itself

Tags: apache, xampp, port

My XAMPP starts Apache on port 80,443, but soon after it changes the port to 53930 or 53530 or something else. Also, no "http://localhost" pages are working at all. MySQL, on the other hand sticks to 3306, but because "http://localhost" is not working, "http://localhost/phpmyadmin" is also not working. Any idea why?

Comment: where did you have changed the port number? Paste php.ini file here

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130952/xampp-ports-change-on-its-own