# Xampp opens odd ports

Tags: apache, networking, xampp, portforwarding

My set up for my xampp has port forwarding, and when I open my xampp this happens is this something I should be concerned about, the Mysql port stays stable the apache one jusps around, what can I do to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP Ports Change On its Own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130952/xampp-ports-change-on-its-own)