# My XAMPP Apache Ports changing automatically when I try to access Phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, server, xampp, port

So, at the first, my XAMPP is working no problem like this
[image]

Note that I have change the port to 8080 because I can't access the default port 80. And when I tried to access `localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/` the Apache ports changes automatically into this

[image]

I thought that XAMPP redirect me to the right port, so i tried to access `localhost:50007/phpmyadmin/`, and i still didn't work either. Does reinstalling XAMPP app is the only solution to this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XAMPP Ports Change On its Own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130952/xampp-ports-change-on-its-own)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this method works on me

1. The first step, you enter the xampp/mysql folder
2. Rename the folder xampp/mysql/data to xampp/mysql/data_old
3. Create a new folder xampp/mysql/data
4. Copy all files in the xampp/mysql/backup folder into the xampp/mysql/data folder you just created
5. Copy all existing database folders in the data_old into the data folder (except MySQL, performance_schema, and 6. phpMyAdmin folders)
   Then copy and replace the ibdata1 file in the data_old folder into the data folder
6. return MySQL on XAMPP
7. finish

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a situation where `XAMPP's port` was changing automatically, and after investigating, I found that the root cause was related to recent changes in my project's code.

It turned out that there was a coding bug in the recent modifications that I made. To troubleshoot the issue, I systematically commented out the recent code changes and observed that the port-changing problem was resolved.

It appears that the code changes were inadvertently causing the automatic adjustment of the port. By identifying and addressing the coding issue, the unexpected port changes were successfully mitigated.

I hope this experience helps others facing similar challenges in ensuring the stability of their local development environments.

Answer (score 0):

reinstalling XAMPP will not work. it's saying that some process is running on port 8080. so you can end that process or change port of apache XAMPP

I will give you the first solution

so `netstat -ano` will give a list of processes with PID

[image]

now find port 8080 and kill the process

> netstat -ano | findstr :8080

now note that PID and run the below command with your `<PID>`

> taskkill /PID  /F

Comment: I've tried that, it will stop the Apache service, right? But when I tried to start it again, the problem is still the same

Comment: @Decrager follow this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)

Comment: I've follow that and try to access `http://localhost:8012/`, and it works. Then I try to open phpmyadmin by `http://localhost:8012/phpmyadmin/`, and the same thing happened, port(s) changing automatically..

Comment: @Decrager - did you find the solution? i am facing the same issue.

Comment: @nilesh No i haven't, i reinstall my xampp instead :)